# Pixel Correspondence from Disparity Map - OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matching, disparity-mapping

I am trying to select a point in the left image and get the corresponding point in the right image.
To start with, I did the stereo calibration and rectified the images, and proceeded to find the disparity map. I used the [StereoSGBM](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html) in OpenCV. Since disparity refers to the distance between two corresponding points in the left and right image of a stereo pair then:

**x_right = x_left - Disparity**

The problem is that when I implement this it doesn't work. Is the problem my interpretation of the disparity map or its output?

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def mouseCallback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global mouseX, mouseY
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        mouseX = x
        mouseY = y
# Images
img_left = cv2.imread(img_path1)
img_right = cv2.imread(img_path2)
# Grayscale
frame_left = cv.cvtColor(img_left,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame_right = cv.cvtColor(img_right,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Retification
...
# Calculate disparity
cv.namedWindow("Stereo Pair Distance")
while True:
   # SGBM Parameters -----------------
   window_size = 3  
   left_matcher = cv.StereoSGBM_create(
   minDisparity=-16, numDisparities=16+16,  
   blockSize=window_size,
   P1=8 * 2 * window_size**2,
   P2=32 * 2 * window_size**2,
   disp12MaxDiff=0,
   uniquenessRatio=5,
   speckleWindowSize=200,
   speckleRange=2,
   preFilterCap=63,
   mode=cv.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY
  )
    right_matcher = cv.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher)
    # FILTER Parameters
    lmbda = 8000
    sigma = 1.4
    # WLS Filter
    wls_filter = cv.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=left_matcher)
    wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
    wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

    # Compute disparity
    displ = left_matcher.compute(left_gray_image, right_gray_image)  
    dispr = right_matcher.compute(right_gray_image, left_gray_image)  
    displ = np.int16(displ)
    dispr = np.int16(dispr)
    filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, left_gray_image, None, dispr)
    filteredImg = cv.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX);
    filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)

    imOut = cv.line(imOut, (640, mouseY),(640*2, mouseY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # Left Point
    imOut = cv.circle(imOut, (mouseX,mouseY), 5,(0,255,0), 3)  
    # Right Point
    Right_X = round(mouseX-filteredImg[mouseX,mouseY])
    imOut = cv.circle(imOut, (Right_X+640,mouseY), 5,(0,255,), 3)

    cv.imshow("Stereo Pair Distance",imOut)
    key = cv.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        # Quit when q is pressed
        break
    
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Stereo Pair Rectified**

[image: Stereo Pair Rectified]

**Stereo Correspondence**

[image: Stereo Correspondence]

**Disparity Map**

[image: Disparity Map]

Comment: did you perhaps swap the left and right pic on accident? In your constellation i would expect `x_left + disparity = x_right`

Comment: numpy indexing is `[i,j]` or `[y,x]` and why would you "normalize" anything here to MINMAX? that destroys the information the disparity map contains values expressing 1/16 of a pixel